# I need to remove the archives from my Wordpress blog.?.?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, archive

I am trying to remove my archives and search bar from the bottom of my blog pages. I have already removed it from my sidebar. Here's my website: www.kylejohnphoto.com. Any help would be appreciated!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from the blog template file

```
<aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://kylejohnphoto.com/">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search…" value="" name="s" title="Search for:">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
</form>
</aside>
<aside id="archives" class="widget">
    <h1 class="widget-title">Archives</h1>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://kylejohnphoto.com/2013/08" title="August 2013">August 2013</a></li>
        </ul>
</aside>
```